# Hartshorne IV 2.2(e) classification of curves of genus 2

Tags: curves

[This is the question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962047/hartshorne-iv-2-2#)

Sorry for asking a repeating question. My problem is just the same as this one. But I don`t understand  the answer.

The answer states"f is uniquely determined by the branch locus." whether it's for a fixed curve X? If so I can understand. However I think it means "X and f are determined uniquely",right? Then I'm confused.

If there are two curves. The morphism determined by canonical divisor K gives the same points in P^1. How can I say they're isomorphic?

I'm really confused.Any help is appreciated.By the way,it`s my first time to raise a question here.Please tell me if I do something wrong…

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand where it is shown that $X,X_2$ are isomorphic if they come with two maps $f,f_2$ to $\Bbb{P}^1$ with the same ramification. If $k=\Bbb{C}$ then I can prove it using that the field extensions are Galois and that they are the field of algebraic functions with prescribed monodromy.

Comment: @reuns Yes it's what I'm confused.(Thank you for your reply.

Comment: If someone has the answer perhaps they should post it in the linked question instead of here

Comment: @reuns The linked question has been solved. I thought nobody will continue to answer it so I asked it here.I don't understand "field of algebraic functions with prescribed monodromy". Can you explane it?Do you mean the measure at the last of the linked question?  I think It's right although it's not my question.